# Toggle plus sign changing negative

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the `+` to `-` when it's toggled, but having a hard time, could you recommend me of some tutorials on how to accomplish this?

i don't even know where to begin, I have my code:

```
$('span .toggle', $(this)).text('+');
    });

    // display the current li with a '-' marker
    $('p', li).slideDown(delay);
    $('span', li).text('-');
```

However obviously I'm doing something completely wrong.

Here's my fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj58Lm5q/2/)

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to you that the best place to start is with simplicity - that is key.  Start with something you know and gradually build on it.  Break your thing down into steps, save often, experiment very often, and when something breaks, undo.

I suspect this is what you want in your final code? http://jsfiddle.net/qj58Lm5q/4/

```
$(function () {
    $("li.subMenu").click(function () {
        var slideDown = $(this).find(".toggle").text() == "+" ? false : true;
        $(".subMenu-link").slideUp();
        $(".toggle").text('+');

        if (!slideDown) {
            $(this).find('.subMenu-link').slideDown();
            $(this).find('.toggle').text('-');
        }
    });
    $(".subMenu-link").not(':first').hide();
});
```

Note that I removed all CSS, cleaned up some excess HTML for this demo, and nearly scrapped the whole JavaScript.  Work slowly up from there.  Add in your CSS, check.  Add in your HTML, check.  Add in a little bit of script, check.  If anything breaks, ask why, and revert.

As long as you don't give up, you will succeed.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I do appreciate this. Thank you. Howver what I had before was, the "one link" li's once clicked, didn't close the whole li. If you know what I mean. What you have is anything in that container clicked, will close the li. so what do i do to fix this? do I do something like `.subMenu-link < li` ?

Comment: You'll want to do something like this: $("li.subMenu .title") and then reference $(this).parent() : http://jsfiddle.net/qj58Lm5q/6/

Comment: If you enjoy reading, this looks like a pretty good place to learn jQuery.  Experiment a lot with their code. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/  If you experiment in JSFiddle, don't forget to include the jQuery library on the left.  Personally, I prefer to learn by doing a project, like you're doing right now, but you're the master.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qj58Lm5q/3/)

```
   $("li.subMenu").click(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
        var ul =  $(this).find('.toggle');

        if (ul.text() == "+")
        $(ul).text("-");
        else
        $(ul).text("+");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qj58Lm5q/5/)
this is what i have done for you.

```
$("li.subMenu").click(function () {
    $(".subMenu-link",this).toggle("slow", function() {
        var text =$(this).prev().text() == '-' ? '+' : '-';
        $(this).prev().text(text);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickElementId').on('click',function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
  })
```